# Filefields empty on POST submission using WTForms and Flask

Tags: python, forms, apache, flask, wtforms

I have a form which has several other fields and 3 filefields. When the form is submitted, the `request.files` variable is an empty `ImmutableDict`. I cant access the files.

The form looks like this:

```
 class DivaForm(Form):
       ...other fields...
       photo_full = FileField("Photo1")
       photo_med = FileField("Photo2")
       photo_close = FileField("Photo3")
```

and the processing part looks like this:

```
@app.route('/diva', methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def diva():
    form = DivaForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate(): #validates
        filenames = ""
        logging.debug(request.files) #return empty
        for i in ('photo_full', 'photo_med', 'photo_close'):
            file_ = request.files[i]
            if file_:
                logging.debug("file "+i+", name: "+file_.filename)
            if file_ and allowed_file(file_.filename): #simple check of extension
                filename = str(form.uid)+"_"+secure_filename(file_.filename)
                file_.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                filenames += "%s:%s,"%(i,filename)
            else:
                logging.debug("no file "+i)
        save_form(form, filenames)
        return render_template('diva_thanks.html')
    return render_template('diva.html', form=form, submit_url = url_for('diva'))
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Does your form include the attribute [`enctype=multipart/form-data`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/)?  If you forget that, the files will not be sent.

Comment: Yes, it does. Turns out I had 2 ajax scripts bound to the same form, one `ajaxSubmit()`, a plugin, other the normal jQuery `ajax()`. The jquery `ajax()` cant send multipart form, while I'd forgotten to include the jQuery form plugin. So, I had to remove the `ajax()` call and then include this plugin, and everything was fine.